# Why is it giving me active:failed error while installation of mongodb on my ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: mongodb

MongoDB shell version v3.4.1
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
2017-12-06T12:16:58.540+0530 W NETWORK  [main] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: Connection refused
2017-12-06T12:16:58.540+0530 E QUERY    [main] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:234:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first start mongo server at port 27017.

You can do it by executing following command:

```
mongod --port 27017 --dbpath [database_path]
```

Comment: do i need to have my database?? Which database path are you referring to?

Comment: You must create a directory where you want to store your data. (It can be any directory.)

Comment: Please mark it as correct answer if it helped you! :)